Is loss of engine in single engine part 23 aircraft leading to a forced landing categorized as CATASTROPHIC or HAZARDOUS?
For part 23 aircraft (CS-23 or FAR-23), there are some aircraft categories such as Normal 1,2,3 and Commuter. For instance, Cessna Grand Caravan is certified as normal category part 23.
But, it has only one engine, it means if the engine fail (complete loss of thrust), then the aircraft cannot perform continue safe flight and landing (CSFL). It could only perform a forced landing. I have some questions regarding that

Based on part 23, is a forced landing categorized as CATASTROPHIC or only HAZARDOUS?
If it is CATASTROPHIC, it means the probability of loss of engine shall be less than 1E-8 or 1E-7 and not caused by a single failure. Since it is a single engine aircraft, how can it be certified then? is the requirement for the whole powerplant or just powerplant control part?
If it is not CATASTROPHIC, is there any constraint of part 23 aircraft to fly above congested or populated area? Since a forced landing may cause a fatality if it happens in the congested area.

Edit: To summarize and clarify the questions, is total loss of engine in single engine part 23 aircraft (normal and commuter) CATASTROPHIC or HAZARDOUS?

I'd never really thought about it, but I assumed that those risk categories only applied to FAR25 Transport Category cert.

The term CFIT usually has the connotation of unexpected  & avoidable impact with terrain, while a forced landing due to engine failure is neither avoidable nor, for the time between the failure & the landing, unforeseen.  While a forced landing meets the individual words "controlled" and "flight" and "terrain" (though the ideal would be onto, rather than into), I expect that such an occurrence would be considered distinct from a classic CFIT incident & not categorized as such.

14 CFR 32.2000 states "Continued safe flight and landing means an airplane is capable of continued controlled flight and landing, possibly using emergency procedures, without requiring exceptional pilot skill or strength. Upon landing, some airplane damage may occur as a result of a failure condition.". So a failed engine is actually CSFL.

While @foot focused on the CFIT criteria, let also look at the categories you cite: "hazardous" and "catastrophic".
Definitions are found in FAR 25.4:

Hazardous failure condition means a failure condition that would reduce the capability of the airplane or the ability of the flightcrew to cope with adverse operating conditions, to the extent that there would be (i) A large reduction in safety margins or functional capabilities, (ii) Physical distress or excessive workload such that the flightcrew cannot be relied upon to perform their tasks accurately or completely, or (iii) Serious or fatal injuries to a relatively small number of persons other than the flightcrew.

Catastrophic failure condition means a failure condition that would result in multiple fatalities, usually with the loss of the airplane.


These categories are not related to CFIT events, they are used for risk management, the principle being if some failure leads to catastrophic consequences, then the failure rate must be extremely improbable, while if the consequences are only minor (another category) a frequent failure rate is acceptable. This principle is the base of risk management and mitigation in any field, and each combination can be associated with a low/medium/high/exceptional risk rating (example).
Overall the categories+likelihood combinations defines two regions:

Source.
To be airworthy, an aircraft must have its parts and systems in the acceptable region, as described in FAR 25.1309 (b):

Each catastrophic failure condition (i) Must be extremely improbable; and (ii) Must not result from a single failure.

Each hazardous failure condition must be extremely remote.


and (e):

The applicant must establish certification maintenance requirements as necessary to prevent the development of the failure conditions described in paragraph (b) of this section.

Answer to your comment

But for a single engine aircraft, is it CAT for having a forced emergency landing due to total loss of engine? If yes, than how to comply with the part 23 requirement for CAT?

The categories do not relate to the cause of a failure, so an engine failure cannot be catastrophic, but it can lead to catastrophic consequences. If a single cause can lead to catastrophic consequences, it's an unacceptable combination, the aircraft cannot be certified.
Single-engine aircraft are designed to be able to glide and land without their engine, the consequences are not catastrophic, per the definition above. If this risk occurs, the crew may have a hard time, but that's almost always manageable, and crews are specifically trained for this occurrence (e.g. when in VMC, they are trained to continuously identify safe places to land, in case an emergency landing should be required).

Hi thank you for the answer. Based on part 23 requirement, no single failure shall lead to CATASTROPHIC (CAT). But for a single engine aircraft, is it CAT for having a forced emergency landing due to total loss of engine? If yes, than how to comply with the part 23 requirement for CAT?

Thanks! By "landing without engine" it means having a forced landing outside of runway right?

@ZahiAzmi: Not necessarily, but the height above the ground will limit its gliding distance, so a forced landing in the countryside is usual (and possible, @ foot gave an extended rationale about emergency landings).

14 CFR 23.2000 states: "Continued safe flight and landing means an airplane is capable of continued controlled flight and landing, possibly using emergency procedures, without requiring exceptional pilot skill or strength. Upon landing, some airplane damage may occur as a result of a failure condition." Also Part 25 does not apply.

Isn't there a phase during the initial climb after takeoff (or even still on the ground, before take-off, after what is, I believe, called V1) where single-engine loss (single reason) would be catastrophic because a controlled stop or emergency landing is impossible during that phase so that a crash is assured?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: In the balanced field takeoff, if the aircraft reaches V1 with all engines it can take off, accelerate, reach V2 and fly safely with one engine inoperative. Of course balanced field takeoff doesn't apply to single-engine aircraft. If the engine failure occurs before V1, the aircraft can safely stop on the runway.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: Not really. One could set up a scenario where it would be that way, but in ordinary operation, the takeoff briefing is something like "If fails before takeoff, stop. If fails below XXX altitude (typically a few hundred feet), land on remaining runway. Between XXX and YYY altitude, choose best spot within 30 degrees of straight ahead and land there. Above yyy altitude (typically 1000 feet), return to airport. There do exist airports where that middle bit is a problem, but it is not guaranteed death, unlike the wings falling off.

The FAA defines CFIT as:

an unintentional collision with terrain (the ground, a mountain, a body of
water, or an obstacle) while an aircraft is under positive control.

An emergency landing is not CFIT, as it would not be unintentional. Part 23 also defines CSFL as:

Continued safe flight and landing   means an airplane is capable of continued controlled flight and landing, possibly using emergency procedures, without requiring exceptional pilot skill or strength. Upon landing, some airplane damage may occur as a result of a failure condition.

Since performing an emergency landing is a required skill to get a pilot license, I don't think that would be considered as "requiring exceptional pilot skill."
Additionally, part 91 defines minimum altitudes for operation (except when necessary for takeoff or landing), including a general requirement:

Anywhere.  An altitude allowing, if a power unit fails, an emergency landing without undue hazard to persons or property on the surface.

So it falls upon the pilot to not operate where an emergency landing would not be possible.

Thank you for your wonderful answer. So based on the CSFL definition, controlled emergency landing due to total loss of thrust is still counted as CSFL, is my understanding correct? Is it also applicable for Commuter category or just Normal category?

@ZahiAzmi, no, it is not CSFL because it is neither continued, nor safe.  Engine failure of a single engine airplane will result in a forced landing.  You will not be able to maintain altitude and continue to your destination as you could in a twin with an engine failure.

@fooot, this is a great explanation to correct the OP's misunderstanding about CFIT.  However, it doesn't answer any of the three numbered questions in the original post.  For that reason it is really just an excellent comment to improve the question.

"an emergency landing without undue hazard to persons or property on the surface". This reg does not require the pilot to operate at an altitude that guarantees the plane can be landed safely for the people onboard- only for people on the ground.
